# What is the C# equivalent of the parameter DateTime ^A?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I've got a big application that's made up of mixed C++/CLI and C# code.  In the course of refactoring, I'd like to create an interface in C# that will be inherited in C++/CLI.  No problem, I've done that many times in the past.  But I'm having a problem with the method signatures of this new interface.  The C++ classes that will be inheriting from it have a method that looks like this.

```
void MethodName(DateTime ^A)
```

If DateTime were a reference type in C#, I could just replace the above signature with this.

```
void MethodName(DateTime A)
```

The problem comes in because DateTime is a value type.  But, it is accessed via a handle.  A handle is a C++/CLI concept and I don't know how to translate it to C#.

Can anyone out there tell me what method signature is required in C# to solve this problem?

Comment: I think this is compiled as `object A` by C++/CLI together with some attribute.

Comment: as an alternative, can you add a wrapper method to your C++ thats compatible for C# and simply proxies to the other Method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct C# equivalent to `DateTime^` in C++/CLI. That type of parameter just doesn't exist in C#.

`ref DateTime` is close, but that would be `DateTime%` in C++/CLI, not `DateTime^`.

If you can modify the source code that has `DateTime^` in it, change it to either `DateTime` or `DateTime%`. It could be that the original author wasn't aware that `DateTime` didn't need the `^`, so they may be using that parameter just as a regular by-value parameter, rather than a by-ref. Whichever way you change it, it will be easily callable from C#.

Comment: I had a feeling this might be the case.  It's a shame as it will require me to make a lot of changes for what should be a simple reorganization.  I'll give it a little while for an answer to appear before I accept this.

Comment: Correction to my answer: It may be that the original author wasn't aware that `DateTime` didn't need the `^`, so the original intent may be `DateTime`, rather than `DateTime%`. Take a look at how the DateTime parameter is being used, and if it's not being used as an input/output parameter, then remove the `^`, and switch all the `->` to `.`.

Comment: +1 for informing me what DateTime% means. I'm looking through old code and I stopped C++ dev before this came in.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible

ILDasm shows this method compiles as

```
void MethodName (
    class [mscorlib]System.ValueType
    modopt([mscorlib]System.DateTime)
    modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsBoxed) 
    A
) cil managed
```

Which is impossible to represent in C# (you cannot encode arbitrary modopt values; these are not attributes)

Why aren't you just using DateTime without the `^`? I don't know what benefit you get from using a handle, since DateTime objects are immutable and small.

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference, in C# you should use the keyword ref:

```
void MethodName(ref DateTime A)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That doesn't work for me for some reason.  "ref" was the first thing I tried.  But when I use "void MethodName(ref DateTime A)" c++/cli seems to expect a signature of void MethodName(DateTime %A).